# App will not start on phone. Using Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get my computer to run an android app on my phone. My computer is running Ubuntu 11.10 and my phone is HTC Desire running 2.2. Here is the error I am getting in Console in Eclipse:

```
[2011-12-13 19:35:05 - InitialChoice2] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-12-13 19:35:05 - InitialChoice2] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-12-13 19:35:05 - InitialChoice2] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.android.taskreminder' in a shell.
[2011-12-13 19:35:05 - InitialChoice2] Launch canceled!
```

I have tried renaming the package but have just gotten the same error. My phone is also in HTC Sync mode and I have tried changing that around. I have tried to open the adb shell but to no avail. I am a bit confused how to use it in linux and when I navigate to the directory in Terminal that the adb is located in, I get another error that says it does not recognize adb command. I suppose I am not sure how to execute "adb uninstall com.android.taskreminder"  properly. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you really change the package name? or did you just rename the file? Those are two very different things.

Comment: I was doing more than changing just the file name. But not enough more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to uninstall it from your phone. go to "Settings" > "Applications" > "Manage Applications" Look for the application name. Select it. There should be an option to uninstall it.

if you want to use adb in a shell, try sudo adb....

Comment: I thought I could just drag the apps into the trash and that would delete it, but this actually deleted the old app.

Comment: On the home screen, dragging the app into the trash is just removing the shortcut from the home screen.

Comment: Dragging icons to the trash deletes the icon only but if you hold the icon there for a few seconds it will uninstall it instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try uninstalling the application through the phone first. This error is usually when you have installed the application in two different ways, so it has a different development signature so cannot update or reinstall.